# cbind arbitrary length vectors with no warning

Tags: r

I would like to `cbind` different vectors of non-multiple length. The shorter ones are to be (partly) recycled as in vanilla `cbind`:

```
cbind(c(1,2,3),c(4,5))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    4
Warning message:
In cbind(c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 5)) :
number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
```

The result is as desired, except for the warning. Since I want to use this in an extension, is there a possibility to suppress the warning or better: who knows a straightforeward solution producing the same results with no warning! -- thanks, S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option, wrapping the key concept into a function that arranges for things to just work. The simplest way is just to use `rep()` on each element of `...` to repeat each input vecotr in `...` to a common length (i.e. the length of the longest input vector).

This is what I do below using the `length.out` argument of `rep()`.

```
CBIND <- function(..., deparse.level = 1) {
  dots <- list(...) ## grab the objects passed in via ... this is a list
  len <- sapply(dots, length) ## find lengths of individual vectors
  ## this applies rep() over dots extending each component vector to length
  ## of longest vector in ...
  dots <- lapply(seq_along(dots),
                 function(i, x, len) rep(x[[i]], length.out = len),
                 x = dots, len = max(len))
  ## need to put everything together so arrange for a call to cbind
  ## passing the extended list of vectors and passing along
  ## the deparse.level argument of cbind
  do.call(cbind, c(dots, deparse.level = deparse.level))
}
```

This gives:

```
R> CBIND(c(1,2,3),c(4,5))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    4
R> CBIND(c(1,2,3),c(4,5), deparse.level = 2)
     c(1, 2, 3) c(4, 5, 4)
[1,]          1          4
[2,]          2          5
[3,]          3          4
```

I would certainly favour this over simply clobbering warnings with `suppressWarnings()` wrapped around the call. For production code you want to explicitly handle the cases you want to allow and let warnings propagate in circumstances where the user has done something you didn't account for.

Comment: Point taken. IMHO using `suppressWarnings` could still be used if the arguments passed to `cbind` are checked beforehand for other problems.

Comment: What if the user passed in something that wasn't numeric or a data frame or...? You might catch them with exhaustive testing, but you might miss the one case that bites a user because you didn't think of it. I agree that `suppressWarnings()` could reasonably be used here, but not in production code.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `suppressWarnings`, if you really want:

```
suppressWarnings(cbind(c(1,2,3),c(4,5)))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    4
# [2,]    2    5
# [3,]    3    4
```

Comment: Oh, that's nice to know! I asked for it, so thank you, but I might go with Gavins solution, which you might also recommend, if I correctly interprete your >..., if you really want< part.